# getting PHP Warning in curl_setopt()

Tags: php, curl

I am getting the following **PHP Warning curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long string given**,

for

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTP);.
```

Curl version is 7.19.7

Comment: Make sure, you have the latest libcurl installed. More likely, your version does not have constant `CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS` defined so php assumes it's a string: `CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS`.

Comment: @Leri The version he posted should be supported.
@ OP Make sure your php version is more recent than 5.2.10

Comment: @0xAli - Yup PHP version i am using is 5.3.3

Comment: @Vikas, ok could the problem be in another line? try to comment out other curl_setopt lines. (And is the . in the end a typo?)

Answer (score 0):

`CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS` is introduced in PHP version 5.2.10. Check your PHP it should be equal or greater than that.

Comment: Do you mean PHP version  5.2.10 ?